# Php date format change from variable

Tags: php, datetime

I get php output function from another function and it always returns date in this-like format:

```
2012-05-24 09:05:20
```

So my question is how can i get from variable $p_re["last_login"] format I need? I need to have it like

```
24.5.2012 09:05:20
```

Thank you all I did not find it in any section there are some - changing right from database but i need to "rewrite" format from already output variable. Thank you.

Comment: what is your function? what code did you write? put some thing so that one can suggest you possible ways..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try This code just before displaying date on page

```
$p_re["last_login"]  = date('d.m.Y H:i:s', strtotime($p_re["last_login"]));
```

More info

'd.m.Y' will return 24.05.2012

'd.n.Y' will return 24.5.2012

Comment: This is perfect, thank you ... And if I want to show numbers without "0" (zero) at the begining I just change letters/chatacters, right?

Comment: `j.n.Y` gives you 4.7.2012 instead of 04.07.2012, just in case you don't want leading zeros for days neither.

Comment: And one last - If I want to show name of months? Like May or December in my language I use what? :)

Comment: `j. F Y` shows the month name. To have it in your language, you need to set locale info. For example, to have it in Dutch, you need to call `setlocale (LC_TIME, 'nl_NL');`.

Comment: Locale info in my code or in php settings? Thank you for everything

Comment: I added setlocale function at the begining of the file and still I have english locale ...

Comment: I am sorry but not getting why you need locale to change date formate?

Comment: I need new output format like from 2012-05-24 09:05:20 to 25. May 2012 09:05:20 but the "May" in my language and setlocale does not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

General answer for custom time formats (needs adjustments):

```
$output = "2012-05-24 09:05:20";

$converted = date("d.m.Y H:i:s", mktime(substr($output,11,2), substr($output,14,2), substr($output,17,2), substr($output,5,2), substr($output,8,2), substr($output,0,4)));
```

Since your output is standard MySQL compound format, you may use

```
$output = "2012-05-24 09:05:20";

$converted = date("d.m.Y H:i:s", strtotime($output));
```

*Instead of `d.m.Y` you can use `d.n.Y` if you want `24.5.2012` and not `24.05.2012` (Note the leading zero in month).*

Answer (score 0):

```
$date_str = '2012-05-24 09:05:20';
```

You can use below statement to format your date according to your desire.

```
$formatted_date = date('Y.m.d H:i:s', strtotime($date_str))
```

Answer (score 0):

A more customisable approach is to use the DateTime object.

Start with making a DateTime object with[DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and then output that with [DateTime::format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).