# php variable date format

Tags: php, date, variables, strtotime

I have a variable 
$date

Which contains a date in the following format: 
'Monday, 24 August 2015'

Or as a strtotime: 
'1440716400'

Id like to change it to the following format:
'24/08/2015'

How can I do this please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert timestamp to readable date/time PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213528/convert-timestamp-to-readable-date-time-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Php date format change from variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733773/php-date-format-change-from-variable)

Answer (score 1):

Simply `date()`

```
$timestamp = strtotime('Monday, 24 August 2015');
echo date("d/m/Y", $timestamp); // Here you put the format you want
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
date("d/m/Y", strtotime('Monday, 24 August 2015'));
```